# Show a column unique text values as tick labels for Y-axis instead of numbers?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to display the below 2 columns in a chart in the following way. The first column should be the values for X axis, the second column should be the unique tick labels for Y axis. So basically a timeline chart with multiple draw points for a particular date.
I can't find any option to change/modify the scaling points displaying the Y-axis to the unique text values of second column.
Is it possible in Google-sheets somehow?

| date | habit |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-10 | habit1 |
| 2023-04-10 | habit2 |
| 2023-04-12 | habit3 |
| 2023-04-17 | habit1 |
| 2023-04-17 | habit3 |
| 2023-04-19 | habit2 |

Wanted result:

```
habit3                  x            x
habit2      x                                     x
habit1      x                        x
       2023-04-10  2023-04-12  2023-04-17   2023-04-19
```

I've come up with this(but I want the other way around - switching the 2 axes):
[image: Habit_X-axis-label_Date_Y-axis-label]

When I tried the transpose version - I've got an *Invalid type* error:
[image: Invalid type error]

Update: I've come to this close to the wanted result - applying Legend on the left:
[image: Legend on the left]

If only this was possible(but I doubt it):
[image: wanted_result]

Comment: It seems so obvious but can't put my finger on it! Transposing your data would be a start though?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this assuming that the data is in a tab called Data and is in columns A and B starting in row 1.

On a completely brand new tab, put this formula in cell A1...

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Data!A1:B},"select Col1,COUNT(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2 label Col1'Habits'",1))
```

Comment: thank you. This should work however I can't display it properly in a chart the way it is represented as pivot table...

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternate approach doing it formulaic way to achieve your *wanted result*

```
=let(row_,unique(torow(A2:A,1),1),col_,sort(unique(tocol(B2:B,1)),1,),
     {{col_;if(,,)},{makearray(counta(col_),counta(row_),lambda(r,c,index(if(ifna(xmatch(index(col_,r)&index(row_,,c),B:B&A:A)),"✔",))));row_}})
```

- the formula is dynamic and will `expand to right and downwards` as new data keeps being added to the raw data in *columns A,B*

[image]

Comment: wow! That is something.
However for me the formula is not working - I've got the following error:
    _In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows._

Comment: @SzabK *"I've got the following error..."* Did you check your locale?

Comment: @marikamitsos thanks for the input. I've modified the above function so:

`=let(row_;unique(torow(A1:A;1);TRUE);col_;sort(unique(tocol(B1:B;1));1;);{{col_;if(;;)};{makearray(counta(col_);counta(row_);lambda(r;c;index(if(ifna(xmatch(index(col_;r)&index(row_;;c);B:B&A:A));"✔";))));row_}})`
There is more error in the arrayformula, but I can't figure it out where could be the error in the last part:
`{{col_;if(;;)};makearray(counta(col_);counta(row_);lambda(r;c;index(if(ifna(xmatch(index(col_;r)&index(row_;;c);B:B&A:A));"✔";))));row_}}`

Comment: use: `=let(row_;unique(torow(A2:A;1);1);col_;sort(unique(tocol(B2:B;1));1;);{{col_;if(;;)}\{makearray(counta(col_);counta(row_);lambda(r;c;index(if(ifna(xmatch(index(col_;r)&index(row_;;c);B:B&A:A));"✔";))));row_}})`